# How to get core temperature of AMD Phenom II X4 955?

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, amd, temperature

`lsmod | grep temp` returns `k10temp 16384  0` and here's sensors reading:

[image]

seems like none of these are core temperature!

Comment: check out `lm_sensors`

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: @ron, probably the `sensor-detect` of `lm_sensors` loaded the `k10temp` module.

Comment: @cas, ok, next time!